# XML to Dataframe, parsing issues

Tags: r, xml-parsing, xml2

Using the XML2 package, I am having issues parsing the data to get it organized into a dataframe. The "header" data in the beginning is confusing xmlParse. I just want the info in all of the REPORT_DATA elements into a dataframe.

I have code that gets the file below into a temp file fine, but manipulating it from there is an issue for me. I am new to xml data-wrangling.

URL: http://oasis.caiso.com/oasisapi/SingleZip?queryname=SLD_REN_FCST&market_run_id=RTPD&startdatetime=20200711T00:00-0000&enddatetime=20200712T00:00-0000&version=1

This is a sample of the above xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><OASISReport xmlns="http://www.caiso.com/soa/OASISReport_v1.xsd">
<MessageHeader>
<TimeDate>2020-07-18T19:13:48-00:00</TimeDate>
<Source>OASIS</Source>
<Version>v20140401</Version>
</MessageHeader>
<MessagePayload>
<RTO>
<name>CAISO</name>
<REPORT_ITEM>
<REPORT_HEADER>
<SYSTEM>OASIS</SYSTEM>
<TZ>PPT</TZ>
<REPORT>SLD_REN_FCST</REPORT>
<MKT_TYPE>RTPD</MKT_TYPE>
<UOM>MW</UOM>
<INTERVAL>ENDING</INTERVAL>
<SEC_PER_INTERVAL>900</SEC_PER_INTERVAL>
</REPORT_HEADER>
<REPORT_DATA>
<DATA_ITEM>RENEW_FCST_15MIN_MW</DATA_ITEM>
<OPR_DATE>2020-07-10</OPR_DATE>
<INTERVAL_NUM>81</INTERVAL_NUM>
<INTERVAL_START_GMT>2020-07-11T03:00:00-00:00</INTERVAL_START_GMT>
<INTERVAL_END_GMT>2020-07-11T03:15:00-00:00</INTERVAL_END_GMT>
<VALUE>11.38</VALUE>
<TRADING_HUB>NP15</TRADING_HUB>
<RENEWABLE_TYPE>Solar</RENEWABLE_TYPE>
</REPORT_DATA>
<REPORT_DATA>
<DATA_ITEM>RENEW_FCST_15MIN_MW</DATA_ITEM>
<OPR_DATE>2020-07-10</OPR_DATE>
<INTERVAL_NUM>83</INTERVAL_NUM>
<INTERVAL_START_GMT>2020-07-11T03:30:00-00:00</INTERVAL_START_GMT>
<INTERVAL_END_GMT>2020-07-11T03:45:00-00:00</INTERVAL_END_GMT>
<VALUE>0</VALUE>
<TRADING_HUB>NP15</TRADING_HUB>
<RENEWABLE_TYPE>Solar</RENEWABLE_TYPE>
</REPORT_DATA>
<REPORT_DATA>
<DATA_ITEM>RENEW_FCST_15MIN_MW</DATA_ITEM>
<OPR_DATE>2020-07-10</OPR_DATE>
<INTERVAL_NUM>80</INTERVAL_NUM>
<INTERVAL_START_GMT>2020-07-11T02:45:00-00:00</INTERVAL_START_GMT>
<INTERVAL_END_GMT>2020-07-11T03:00:00-00:00</INTERVAL_END_GMT>
<VALUE>56.89</VALUE>
<TRADING_HUB>NP15</TRADING_HUB>
<RENEWABLE_TYPE>Solar</RENEWABLE_TYPE>
</REPORT_DATA>
</REPORT_ITEM>
<DISCLAIMER_ITEM>
<DISCLAIMER>The contents of these pages are subject to change without notice.  Decisions based on information contained within the California ISO's web site are the visitor's sole responsibility.</DISCLAIMER>
</DISCLAIMER_ITEM>
</RTO>
</MessagePayload>
</OASISReport>
```

The df would look something like this:

```
      data_item             opr_date      interval_num      value     trading_hub     renewable_type
   RENEW_FCST_15MIN_MW     2020-07-10         81             11.38      NP15             Solar
   RENEW_FCST_15MIN_MW     2020-07-10         83             0          NP15             Solar
          .                    .              .               .          .                 . 
          .                    .              .               .          .                 .
```

So far, I have done this:

```
test <- xmlParse(file = "/tmp/datafile.xml")
data <- xmlToDataFrame(test)
```

And this doesn't give me what I want. It jams all the actual data into a single cell labelled RTO. I've also looked at the xml2 docs and tinkered with some of the functions, but can't get them to extract only the REPORT_DATA attributes and data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
test <- xmlParse(file = "data/20200710_20200711_SLD_REN_FCST_RTPD_20200718_14_49_12_v1.xml")
data <- xmlToDataFrame(xpathApply(test, '//*[local-name() = "REPORT_DATA"]'))
```

to produce this:
[image]

Comment: I need to do the process all in the code, as it will run multiple times per day. So I would need the code to deal with the namespace issue. But this is informative that you got it to work by removing the ns.

Comment: @otterdog2000 I updated it.  Now I don't remove the ns.